# Como ler apenas uma linha do arquivo em C?

Tags: c

Estou estudando arquivo agora, quero apenas que eu consiga ler uma linha do arquivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz este código, mas ele lê tudo. Já tentei usar o fscanf, fgetc, fgets, "\n"; entretanto não encontrei solução. Podem me ajudar? Queria a forma mais simples possível.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    FILE *p;
    if((p=fopen("votos.txt","r"))== NULL){
        printf("\n Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo");
        exit(0);
    }
    char c;
    while(!feof(p))
    {
        c = fgetc(p);
        printf("%c", c);
    }
    fclose(p);
}
```

Comment: O que as funções `feof` e `fgetc` que você utilizou fazem?

Comment: fgetc lê um caracter. Feof foi usado no while -> enquanto não chegar ao final do arquivo(EOF)

Comment: E se ao invés de executar até o final do arquivo você fizesse até ele achar o caractere `\n`?

Comment: É sabido que cada linha tem sempre 3 dígitos? Qual o tamanho máximo que o arquivo pode ter? Tem alguma restrição do que pode fazer?

Comment: Especifica mais o que você quer fazer. Um simples fscanf já lê apenas uma linha e posiciona o ponteiro no local certo para a próxima leitura

Comment: Eu já tentei até usar \n e o scanf, não consegui. Maniero, o arquivo é só isso mesmo, eu só queria mostrar na tela apenas uma linha dessas.

Comment: Se você quiser armazenar toda a linha antes de exibi-la então terá que reservar espaço para todos os seus caracteres. Para ler toda a linha a função gets, ou melhor ainda a fgets, é mais indicada. Explique melhor o que deseja fazer.

Comment: Para usar essas funções eu teria que limitar, porque elas usam tamanho máximo, como eu limitaria?

Comment: Qual o máximo tamanho possível de uma linha? 1000, 3000, 10000 caracteres?

Comment: Você disse que o arquivo é esse então você sabe o tamanho da linha e do arquivo, por isso a melhor solução é ler o arquivo todo de uma vez e jogar no buffer e aí pegar cada linha porque sabe que tem tamanho 4 (pode ser 5 dependendo do formato da quebra de linha), não tem porque complicar ou deixar mais lento do que deveria como está querendo fazer e estão te sugerindo.

Comment: Se você apenas tem apenas um numero em cada linha do arquivo, consegue ler eles facilmente com `fscanf(arquivo, " %d", &variavel_para_o_numero_lido);`

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso, penso que a solução mais fácil seria:

```
int main(){
    FILE *p;
    if((p=fopen("votos.txt","r"))== NULL){
        printf("\n Nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo");
        exit(0);
    }

    int val;
    fscanf(p, "%d", &val);
    printf("%d", val);

    fclose(p);
}
```

Lê o primeiro interio e coloca na variável `val`. Na próxima chamada, `fscanf` leria o segundo valor, e assim sucessivamente.